# Add a parent node to Json output in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have converted some info to Json format using Jackson in Java. Below is the output I get

`[{"lat":45.9,"lon":10.9,"title":"Title A1","html":"<h3>Content A1</h3>","icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png"},{"lat":44.8,"lon":1.7,"title":"Title B1","html":"<h3>Content B1</h3>","icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerB.png","show_infowindow":false},{"lat":51.5,"lon":-1.1,"title":"Title C1","html":"<h3>Content C1</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum..</p>","zoom":8,"icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerC.png"}]`

My question is how can I get it in the below format, basically adding the Json to a root node which called locations

`{"locations":[{"lat":45.9,"lon":10.9,"title":"Title A1","html":"<h3>Content A1</h3>","icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png"},{"lat":44.8,"lon":1.7,"title":"Title B1","html":"<h3>Content B1</h3>","icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerB.png","show_infowindow":false},{"lat":51.5,"lon":-1.1,"title":"Title C1","html":"<h3>Content C1</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum..</p>","zoom":8,"icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerC.png"}]}`

Comment: Need to add a partner node to my Json.

Comment: Thanks for editing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wrap the array into a JSONObject like so

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

String json = jsonArray.toString();
map.put("locations", json);

json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by following changes.

Let's Assume, your JSON will be created based upon Bean.java class likewise,

```
[{"lat":45.9,"lon":10.9,"title":"Title A1","html":"<h3>Content A1</h3>","icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png"},{"lat":44.8,"lon":1.7,"title":"Title B1","html":"<h3>Content B1</h3>","icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerB.png","show_infowindow":false},{"lat":51.5,"lon":-1.1,"title":"Title C1","html":"<h3>Content C1</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum..</p>","zoom":8,"icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerC.png"}]
```

Now, As per your new requirement, you want something likewise,

```
{"locations":[{"lat":45.9,"lon":10.9,"title":"Title A1","html":"<h3>Content A1</h3>","icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png"},{"lat":44.8,"lon":1.7,"title":"Title B1","html":"<h3>Content B1</h3>","icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerB.png","show_infowindow":false},{"lat":51.5,"lon":-1.1,"title":"Title C1","html":"<h3>Content C1</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum..</p>","zoom":8,"icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerC.png"}]}
```

So, in this case you need to create one more class, let's say it's `SuperBean.java` then it should be likewise,

```
public class SuperBean {
     private Bean [] locations;

    public Bean[] getBean() {
        return locations;
    }

    public void setBean(Bean[] locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }
}
```

So, your JSON will be created likewise,

```
{"locations":[......]} // as per your requirement.
```